# How to synchronize socket SID on server and client?

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I have `python_socketio 5.0.4` on client and `Flask-SocketIO 5.0.1` on server. When client connects to server, I would like to synchronize client's SID between client and server. However, when I print SID on client, it's different from SID printed on server.

Is there any way to make SID of client same on server as on client?

Here is code for client:

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()
sio.connect("http://localhost:5000")
print(sio.sid)  # czNJ6NXIAXP9-vgmAAAK
sio.emit("test_event")
```

And here for server:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
sio = SocketIO(app)

@sio.on("test_event")
def test_event():
    print(request.sid)  # ukJhK9ZIiXY_gTMAAAL   <---   this is different SID

sio.run(app)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the 5.x Flask-SocketIO, thanks for letting me know, I'll fix it.

Comment: Actually, no, this is working fine, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the client you are accessing your `sid` as `sio.sid`. The `sid` property of the Socket.IO client is private, it is not supposed to be used.

Instead, use the `sio.get_sid()` method to obtain the `sid`. This used to not be a problem, but in the latest revision of the Socket.IO protocol each namespace is required to have a different `sid`, so the `get_sid()` method should be used to obtain the correct one for your namespace.

If you were using a non-default namespace you can pass it as an argument as follows: `sio.get_sid(namespace='/my-namespace')`.